# How to print data to the terminal as it comes in off the socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing an IRC bot (still) and I've been stumped here for months.
I wrote this function for receiving data and printing it out, simple stuff, except it doesn't always work.
For example, when the bot connects to a server, the server sends the MoTD, and when this function here tries to print it out there's usually a couple of lines chopped off at the very end.

```
int mainLoop(int socketDescriptor)
{
    int bytesReceived = 0, i;
    char workingBuffer[RECVBUFF];

    do
    {
        for (i = 0; i < RECVBUFF; i += bytesReceived)
        {
            bytesReceived = recv(
                    socketDescriptor,
                    workingBuffer + i,
                    RECVBUFF - i,
                    0);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < RECVBUFF; ++i)
            printf("%c", workingBuffer[i]);
    }
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some screenshots showing the output of my program and the output of a client like irssi.

[image: My program's output]
[image: Irssi's output]

As you can see my program just stalls on that last chunk and stops printing.
How can I fix this?

Comment: As those screenshots only show text, is there any chance you might post the raw text instead of the pretty pictures? Snip the MotD to a manageable 3 lines or so, with snip indicator...

Comment: Showing the terminal text as _text_ is more useful than showing as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `for` loop never exits unless the buffer is full. The last part of the response is unlikely to exactly fill the buffer. <strike>Something like this might help:</strike>

```
for (i = 0; i < RECVBUFF; i += bytesReceived)
{
    bytesReceived = recv(
            socketDescriptor,
            workingBuffer + i,
            RECVBUFF - i,
            0);

    if (!bytesReceived)
        break;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
bytesReceived = 1; /* so the loop does at least one iteration */

for (i = 0; i < RECVBUFF && bytesReceived; i += bytesReceived)
{
    bytesReceived = recv(
            socketDescriptor,
            workingBuffer + i,
            RECVBUFF - i,
            0);
}
```

OK, new plan -- simplest (probably not best) solution:

```
int mainLoop(int socketDescriptor)
{
    int bytesReceived = 0, i;
    char workingBuffer[RECVBUFF];

    do
    {
        bytesReceived = recv(
                socketDescriptor,
                workingBuffer,
                RECVBUFF,
                0);

        for (i = 0; i < bytesReceived; ++i)
            printf("%c", workingBuffer[i]);
    }
    while(bytesReceived);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But won't recv() just block if there are 0 bytes waiting on the socket?

Comment: Yes, it will.  recv() returning 0 indicates that the peer closed the connection.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, that's no good either. I guess the first `for` loop should just be discarded -- do a `printf()` after every `recv()`. Or, use `select()` to check for pending input. Or set the socket to non-blocking...